# Bluetooth between iPad Mini and Mac Pro keeps dropping

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, mojave

- Mac Pro (early 2009) 4,1 -> 5,1
- macOS 10.14.1 Mojave (using dosdude1.com/mojave)
- iPad Mini 2
- iOS 12.1

Hello, I am trying to connect my newly bought (but second hand) iPad to my Mac Pro using bluetooth so that I can take advantage of the Universal Clipboard facility. However, as soon as I pair the iPad and the Mac Pro, the connection drops after a second or so. It doesn't even allow me time to investigate the RSSI settings.

I know that the bluetooth on the Mac Pro is working because I am using a Magic Keyboard connected by bluetooth with no problems whatsoever.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pair your iPad to your Mac. This feature is part of Handoff, which is part of the Continuity family of features.

In order for this to work, you need to turn the feature on, on all your devices:
*from Apple:*

- Each device is signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID.
- Each device has Bluetooth turned on.
- Each Mac, iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch has Wi-Fi turned on.
- Each device has Handoff turned on:
  Mac: Choose Apple () menu > System Preferences, then click General. Select “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices.”
- Each device has Handoff turned on:
  Mac: Choose Apple () menu > System Preferences, then click General. Select “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices.”
  iPhone, iPad, iPod touch: Go to Settings > General > Handoff, then turn on Handoff.

Finally, you need to ensure your device supports the feature. For Universal Clipboard, your Mac should be: MacBook (Early 2015 or newer); MacBook Pro (2012 or newer); MacBook Air (2012 or newer;  Mac mini (2012 or newer); iMac (2012 or newer); iMac Pro; Mac Pro (Late 2013).

For iDevices: iPhone 5 or newer; iPad Pro; iPad (4th generation) or newer; iPad Air or newer; iPad mini 2 or newer; iPod touch (6th generation) or newer.

If you don't have one of these devices the features won't work.

For more see Apple support: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689

Comment: I don't seem to have the Handoff option available, but then since my Mac is an early 2009 model, maybe I'm SOL! In any case I've found an app called Copied which seems to do the job pretty well, if not as seemlessly as UC.